# How to perform a POST with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

```js
    await page.evaluate(async ({ contactList, fLen, pauseArray }) => {

        function searchContact(contact_name = "") {
            search = document.querySelector('#side > div._1Ra05 > div > label > div > div._1awRl.copyable-text.selectable-text');
            search.textContent = contact_name;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 99999999; i++) {

            const body = 
            { 
                "lastseen": 1
            };

            const response = await fetch('https://nicpp.herokuapp.com/api/users/lastseen', { method: 'post', body: JSON.stringify(body), headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }});
            const json = await response.text();
            console.log(json);

            for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
                searchContact(contactList[i]);

                await new Promise(function(resolve) {setTimeout(resolve, 100)});
                title = document.querySelector("#main > header > div._2aNms > div._2fKRJ > div > span").title;

                lastseen = "";
                try {
                        lastseen = document.querySelector("#main > header > div._2aNms > div._2Gdma._2amHe > span").innerText;
                } 
                catch(error)
                {};
                    
                console.log(i,':       ',title,lastseen);               
            }
        }

    },{contactList,fLen});
```

Trying to perform a post while using puppeteer, when I run it outside the `(async () =>` it does work, but when I run inside `await page.evaluate(async` it throws this error:

Error:

```
Debugger attached.
(node:8076) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:101:27
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (c:\Users\ZAP\Desktop\Nova pasta\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:217:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (c:\Users\ZAP\Desktop\Nova pasta\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:106:16)
    at async c:\Users\ZAP\Desktop\Nova pasta\zap.js:66:2
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8076) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8076) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Process exited with code 1
(node:8544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I can see this message on chrome console:

[image]

Im trying to do a post containing the lastseen data that I read before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to bypass CSP using `await page.setBypassCSP(true)`.

[Documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagesetbypasscspenabled)